# O caixa de supermercado, a caixa de supermercado?

Tags: gênero, substantivos

> Senti-me atraído sexualmente pela caixa de supermercado.

A frase acima é comicamente ambígua. Minha pergunta é se está gramaticamente correta quando alude a uma atendente: o gerente, a gerente; o dentista, a dentista; o caixa, **a** caixa?

Comment: Vendo textos brasileiros, parece-me é haver uma confusão com o género de outro significado de _caixa_: «estive nas Americanas da Ataulfo de Paiva 1251 Leblon e não é a 1.a vez que sou mal atendida pela mesma funcionária do caixa ( que se encontra na 2.a caixa de pagamento da entrada para os fundos da loja)», «Eu lhe disse que por estarmos com poucos itens, na verdade apenas 3 itens além dos 15 permitidos praquele caixa,»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, será **o caixa** para um homem ou para uma referência genérica (e.g. *o caixa médio tem 32 anos*, *o melhor caixa deste estabelecimento é a Maria*) ou **a caixa** para uma mulher. Isto pode ser confirmado em qualquer dicionário, que marca o nome como tendo dois géneros:

[Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/caixa):

> **substantivo de dois géneros**
>   16. Empregado que tem a caixa a seu cargo, nomeadamente uma caixa registadora.

[Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/caixa)

> **s2g.**
>   13. Funcionário que trabalha em caixa (5).